# iOS filtering an array

Tags: ios, uitableview, filter, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array of data that is displayed in a table. The array has multiple fields, including two specific ones I want to filter, the "call type" and the "county". The value for "call type" is either an "f" or "e" and the value for the county is either "w" or "c". I want to have 4 UISwitch's to to either turn on/off the "w", turn on/off the "c" etc. Its hard to explain but if you go to this website and look at the top right corner, its exactly what I want to do. http://www.wccca.com/PITS/ Out of the 4 filters, two filters control the county field, and two filters control the call type field. but they all operate independently. How would I go about accomplishing this? Would I use NSPredicate to create a new array each time something is filtered or what? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use an `NSPredicate` for this. Probably the easiest thing to do would be to use the same `IBAction` for all four switches and have it do a recalculation:

```
- (IBAction)anySwitchDidChange:(id)sender
{
    // make a set of all acceptable call types
    NSMutableSet *acceptableCallTypes = [NSMutableSet set];
    if(self.fSwitch.on) [acceptableCallTypes addObject:@"f"];

    // ... etc, to create acceptableCallTypes and acceptableCounties

    NSPredicate *predicate = 
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                            @"(%@ contains callType) and (%@ contains county)", 
                            acceptableCallTypes, acceptableCounties];

    /*
       this predicate assumes your objects have the properties 'callType' and 
       'county', and that you've filled the relevant sets with objects that would
       match those properties via isEqual:, whether strings or numbers or
       anything else.

       NSDictionaries are acceptable since the internal mechanism used here is
       key-value coding.
    */

    NSArray *filteredArray = [_sourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    // send filteredArray to wherever it needs to go
}
```

Using `predicateWithFormat:` causes the text to be parsed right there and then. In this case that should be no problem whatsoever but in general you can create the predicates in advance and supply only the parameters at the relevant moment, should you ever end up using one in a really time critical area.